# Data is not inserting oracle table using ODP.NET through asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I am inserting record in Oracle table using ODP.NET Oracle.DataAccess.Client throug Asp.net c#.
The oracle table is  tblGroup and GROUPNAME varchar2,GROUPDETAILS varchar2 is column name
but data is not inserting.I am using following code

```
 public void insertRecord(string StudentgroupName, string groupDetails) 
            {
                using (OracleConnection con = GetConnection())
                {

                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con; //assigning connection to command
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //representing type of command
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblGroup (GROUPNAME,GROUPDETAILS) values(@GROUPNAME,@GROUPDETAILS)";

                    //adding parameters with value
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GROUPNAME", StudentgroupName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GROUPDETAILS", groupDetails);

                    con.Open(); //opening connection
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
            }
```

and got following error

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-00936: missing expression at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck) at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck) at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at SchoolsManagementSystem.DAL.insertRecord(String StudentgroupName, String groupDetails) in d:\c#\SchoolsManagementSystem\SchoolsManagementSystem\App_Code\DAL.cs:line 85 at SchoolsManagementSystem.Group.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\c#\SchoolsManagementSystem\SchoolsManagementSystem\Group.aspx.cs:line 26

Guide me How can I solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SQL statement, use a colon prefix to indicate bind parameter, not @:

```
INSERT INTO t (COL1) values(:param1)
```

Using the @ symbol works ok for SQL Server, for not for Oracle.

Also, your bind statement needs to just use the name "GROUPNAME", no prefix character @ or : needed in the parameters.Add() call.

Like so:

```
cmd.CommandText =
   "INSERT INTO tblGroup (GROUPNAME,GROUPDETAILS) values(:GROUPNAME, :GROUPDETAILS)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("GROUPNAME", StudentgroupName);
cmd.Parameters.Add("GROUPDETAILS", groupDetails);
```

Comment: Interesting note on prefix not needed. I have no Oracle to test, but it raise an error or the prefix is simple ignored by the engine?

Comment: The Oracle SQL parser uses the colon to indicate bind parameters, whether in SQL, PL/SQL or host languages. The ADO driver may or may not complain, but Oracle will. The @ isn't a valid character for an identifier or a bind variable, so possibly you'll get a parse error. I just know it fails, because I have a few database tools that I sell that work on Oracle and SQL Server and I have to use conditional code between the two.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, mine was just curiosity.